# RegEx search non-unicode keyword on unicode string

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on an auto complete function of my website. I have a problem with unicode:

When a user type a keyword, I find title from the database, and then insert  tag to highlight the keyword on the results. I use PHP `preg_match` function to replace `keyword` to `<mark>keyword</mark>`. But I'm stuck with below case:

User type `tieng anh`, result found `tiếng anh cho trẻ`, I also want highlight `tiếng anh` in result.

Other example, user type `cong cu`, result is `các công cụ digital marketing`, `công cụ` should be highlights.

Please help.

Comment: What Regex are you using currently?

Comment: Example user type ```tieng anh```, I used: ```preg_replace("/(tieng|anh)/ui", "<mark>$1</mark>", $title)```

Comment: Maybe it helps you as approach to solve similar problem  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php#84881

Comment: If it is only for highlighting, can you [detect accented characters from target text like in this demo?](https://eval.in/788805) It searches for any accented characters in the target text and builds corresponding search string. Makes only sense if target string is not too much data. Generates pattern such as [`/ti[eếẻ]ng\W+[aá]nh/iu`](https://regex101.com/r/6jyjSq/1/) for `tiếng anh cho trẻ các công`

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match('#key(word)#', $text, matches)` with `var_dump($matches)`

You will see `$matches[0]` is whole string, and `$matches[1]` is what you want.

Comment: I did it but ```tieng anh``` does not match with ```tiếng anh```

Comment: Try `ti(e|ế)ng` instead of `ti[eế]ng`

Comment: If I do that, I have to handle too many case, because I don't know what user type, so I have to split to vowel and consonant :(